# Excel formula to remove number + character from text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is is possible to remove to achieve the following using formula? I want to get rid of the numbers at the end. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: take a look at [split-text-with-delimiter](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter)

Comment: Would there be two different delimiters to differentiate between the number and the rest of the string? Or is the underscore char a typo in your last string?

Comment: @JvdV There be two different delimiters to differentiate between the number and the rest of the string. The underscore is not a typo

Comment: Yes there is. Question has been answered. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possibility with the following assumptions:

- The delimiter to differentiate between number and rest of string can be both `-` or `_`
- There always is a number to be taken off from the string

[image]

The formula used in `B2`:

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","-"),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))))-1)
```

Drag down...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, how is that simplified?

Comment: More or less what Max Voisard suggests below. You don't have to repeat blanks ad nauseam just to remove almost all of them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `LEFT()` function to get rid of text at the end. Sample syntax:

```
LEFT(cell_id,LEN(cell_id)-num_chars)
```

For example, if you wanted to remove the last 3 characters from cell A4:

```
LEFT(A4,LEN(A4)-3)
```

However, in your case, it looks like you want to get rid of text after the last occurrence of a certain delimiter/separator - that being "-" or "_", so try these two:

```
LEFT(A4,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))-1)
```

and

```
LEFT(A4,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))-1)
```

Comment: That would not work for be because the characters to remove is not always 3

Comment: Just replace `_` with `-` before applying the first and it's ok (the trick is to only replace on the part that is used to compute the length to be kept, hence the original `_` are not lost).